# fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first while mounting s3 bucket on a docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, docker-container, s3fs

I have to mount the s3 bucket over docker container so that we can store its contents in an s3 bucket.
I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFTxUlW8_QQ&ab_channel=ValaxyTechnologies video which shows how to do the same process for ec2 instance instead of a docker container.
I am following the same steps as mentioned in the above link. Likewise, I have done the following things on the docker container: 
(Install FUSE Packages)
apt-get install build-essential gcc libfuse-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev mime-support pkg-config libxml++2.6-dev libssl-dev
git clone https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fus...
cd s3fs-fuse
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install

(Ensure you have an IAM Role with Full Access to S3)

(Create the Mountpoint)
mkdir -p /var/s3fs-demo-fs

(Target Bucket)
aws s3 mb s3://s3fs-demo-bkt

But when I trying to mount the s3 bucket using
s3fs s3fs-demo-bkt /var/s3fs-demo-fs -o iam_role=

I am getting the following messege
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first

I have looked over several solutions for this problem. But I am not able to resolve this issue. Please let me know how I can solve it.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem. But later the issue was fixed by adding  `--privileged` when running the docker run command

Comment: The --privilaged fails for me as I am using an airflow docker with sqllite. I later moved on to a different approach. The one mentioned here https://incubator-airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging-monitoring/logging-tasks.html

Comment: This worked fr me, but I'd like to provide privileged mode to docker container while already running. I'm pretty sure this is possible.